# Django formwizard - cannot get data from step 1 to step 2

Tags: python, django, templates, django-forms, django-formwizard

I am using a Django form wizard to enter data into a form page, and then display it in a confirmation page. However, when I try to call self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(step_name), I get a "'MyForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'." I know this can happen if the form fails to validate, so I overrode the is_valid method in my form class to always return True, just as a test, but I still get this error. My relevant code is below:

**forms.py**

```
...
class MealForm(forms.Form):

    modifications = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        menu_items = kwargs.pop('menu_items')
        super(MealForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for item in menu_items:
            self.fields[str(item.name)] = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'value': 0}))

    def is_valid(self):
        return True
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^(?P<url>[-\w]+)/meal/$',
    login_required(views.MealFormWizard.as_view(views.MealFormWizard.FORMS)), name="meal"),
```

**views.py**

```
...
class MealFormWizard(SessionWizardView):

    FORMS = [('meal_form', MealForm),
             ('meal_form_confirmation', MealFormConfirmation)]

    TEMPLATES = {'meal_form': 'restaurant/createMeal.html',
                 'meal_form_confirmation':     'restaurant/confirmation.html'}

    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        kwargs = {}

        url = self.kwargs['url']
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(url=url)
        menu_items = MenuItem.objects.filter(restaurant=restaurant)

        if step == 'meal_form':
            kwargs['menu_items'] = menu_items

        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):

        context = super(MealFormWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)

        if self.steps.current == 'meal_form':
            context.update({...objects/vars...})

        if self.steps.current == 'meal_form_confirmation':
            cd = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('meal_form') **This is where my error occurs**
```

**createMeal.html**

```
...
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ wizard.management_form }}

{{ wizard.form }}

<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.next }}">Submit Meal</button>
</form>
```

Upon submitting the form in createMeal.html I should be able to access the cleaned data for the previous step in the get_context_data method of my MealFormWizard class in views.py via a call to self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('meal_form'). However, this is not the case, but I am not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `is_valid` like that won't work - if you follow the code you will see that the form's `cleaned_data` attribute is set by the normal `is_valid` method.

The docs say that if the form is invalid, then `get_cleaned_data_for_step` will return `None`, you need to write your code so it can handle this.

Comment: I thought overriding the method like this would be fine because in the implementation of is_valid() in the django forms source code, the only thing in the method is "return self.is_bound and not self.errors", so returning True all the time doesn't seem to erase any functionality. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to follow the code a bit further. The `self.errors` property calls `self.full_clean()`, which sets the `cleaned_data` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is helpful to anyone. My problem was that in my createMeal.html, my button was simply taking the wizard to the next step, bypassing any validation. The proper solution is to make a simple submit button to submit the form, at which point the wizard will then validate the form, and if it is valid, it will move on to the next step.